# Escaping special characters or inserting them literally

Tags: tex-core, macos

I have looked far and wide on the Internet on how to do this.
I am writing a doc about macOS in LaTeX.

Here the symbol `⌘` is quite common. I haven't found a way to write thos in LaTeX though.

Comment: `\applecmd` (or `\wasycmd`, it's the same) from `wasysym`.

Comment: Thank you @egreg